# How do you add a "touch to select" on a WinJS ListView?

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I've seen this done in most Microsoft Windows Phone apps where when you tap on the left hand side of a list, and it starts the multi-select mode.

How can you accomplish the same functionality using WinRT/Javascript/WinJS?

Here's a picture of the Mail app to clarify. Pretty sure this has been done with XAML/C#.

[image]

Comment: To get this functionality on the XAML side you have to use `LongListMultiSelector` from wp toolkit. Quick google search didn't bring up any direct equivalents for WinJs.

Comment: @Denis Thanks for the update. Looks like there is currently no support for this functionality. I'm going to make a feature request!